# Is torsion of a connection always an obstruction to some kind of integrability?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a smooth manifold $M$ equipped with a linear connection $\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Omega^1(M;E).$  I say $(M,E,\nabla)$ is flat if it admits trivial local models; i.e. if for each $p \in M$ there is a $\nabla$-parallel local frame for $E$ defined on some neighbourhood of $p$. It is well known (and often instead taken as the definition) that $(M,E,\nabla)$ is flat if and only if the curvature form $R^\nabla \in  \Omega^2(M; E)$ vanishes; so the curvature can be motivated as an obstruction to flatness.

When $E = TM$ so that $\nabla$ is an affine connection, a more restrictive definition is often used: we say $(M,\nabla)$ is flat if each $p \in M$ is contained in a chart whose coordinate frame is $\nabla$-parallel. This imposes an additional requirement on the local model: not only must we be able to choose a frame making $\nabla$ trivial, but this frame must be holonomic. Again, a nice characterization of this kind of flatness is well-known: it's equivalent to both the curvature $R^\nabla$ *and* the torsion $T^\nabla$ vanishing.

Thus in the world of affine connections that are flat in the weaker sense ($R^\nabla = 0$) where we can always find a parallel frame, torsion is exactly what obstructs integrating such a frame to get a chart. This interpretation doesn't feel very satisfying to me, however, since it applies only to flat connections, while in practice we are much more likely to restrict to torsion-free connections before even thinking about curvature.

> **Question.** Without the assumption that $R^\nabla = 0$, can we motivate torsion as the obstruction to some kind of integrability?

This is motivated in part by [this nice answer to a broader question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20506/33510), which describes torsion as an obstruction to the integrability of various $G$-structures; but I'm having trouble seeing how this interpretation can apply in the case of a connection alone.

[This question received no answer after I posted a bounty on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574427/torsion-of-a-connection-as-an-obstruction-to-integrability).

Comment: **Please** do not ask the same question in both sites. If you ask moderators, questions can be *moved*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: ok, sorry, what should I do? Delete this and flag the question on math.SE?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez can it be merged..?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no more suitable reason among the choices listed.  There is an identical question on Math.SE that contains a substantial answer, so further answers should go there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am not sure what was the etiquette then, but it seems acceptable to cross-post now when the links are provided (https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5013/), (see also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4582/). On the other hand, migration from MSE does not seem to be common. In addition, I do not think it a good idea to intimidate posters (such as bolding *please* in the comment).

Comment: @Z.M, I entirely fail to see the point in admonitioning me about a comment on a question that has been closed for three years now, on a point of policy which changed since then — at the time I was a moderator of both sites, so I was more or less well informed about the policies…  On the other hand, I **reserve** the right to embolden whatever word I **choose**.

Comment: This is a three year old closed question, in the name of all gods… I am sure there is something more useful to be done for the sake of **The Site**.